# AWS backup plan not showing backups in vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I'm using a backup plan on AWS backup.

[image]

It looks like the job is running regularly, or at least ran on Aug 4.

[image]

However, when I click on "Default" under "Backup Vault" I don't see anything.

[image]

(The three there are ad hoc backups I did before). <s>How do I find my backups and/or make sure its working?</s>

At @Aram's suggestion in the comments I checked the Jobs menu and I see no jobs. Not sure why this is so.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the Jobs menu and see if the Backup Jobs are successful? Recovery Points displayed under the Backup Vault are the successful ones.

Comment: @Aram thanks! I checked, and I see the Jobs menu is all empty (no jobs run I suppose).

Comment: Yes, that means something isn't setup properly for the plan to work

Comment: Pleas check the settings of Backup and see if you have opted-in for the resources to Backup.